# Possible error in Php: Everything below the header is invisible in firefox, but works fine in chrome

Tags: php, mysql, html

Here's the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>emarket.com</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css"/>
    </head>
    <header>
        <h1><a href="index.php" style="text-decoration:none">emarket.com</a></h1>
        <h1><a href="postad.php" style="text-decoration:none; padding-left:700px">Post Ad</a></h1>
    </header>
    <body>

        <?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $description=$_POST['description'];
    $district=$_POST['district'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $catagory=$_POST['catagory'];
    $price=$_POST['price'];

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("maindb");

    mysql_query("INSERT into allads VALUES(NULL,'$title','$phone','$description', '$price','$district','$catagory')");
    echo "<span style='background-color: deepskyblue;'>Your advert is now online!</span>";
}
        ?>


        <form class="postad" method="post" action="">
            <fieldset><caption><h2>Post New Advert</h2></caption></fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label>Title</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="title" class="form-text" required>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label>Description</label><br/>
                <input  name="description" class="form-text" required>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label>District</label><br/>
                <select name="district"required>
                    <option selected>Colombo</option>
                    <option>Kandy</option>
                    <option>Matara</option>
                    <option>Galle</option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label>Category</label><br/>
                <select name="catagory"required>
                    <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
                    <option value="Property">House and Property</option>
                    <option value="Auto">Automobiles</option>
                    <option value="Misc">Miscellaneous</option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label>Phone</label><br/>
                <input type="tel" name="phone" maxlength="10" class="form-text" required>
            </fieldset>         
            <fieldset>
                <label>Price</label><br/>
                Rs. <input type="number" name="price" class="form-text" required>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This happened after I entered the PHP parts, it was visible in Firefox before that. Other files having PHP, like the home page, works fine. In chrome not only the website is visible, it works fine too. Stuff from the form gets inserted into the sql table without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the slightest idea of how vulnerable you are to mysql injection attacks? Please start using pdo. mysql_* is deprecated.

I've cleaned the function for you. The php part will only be executed once you click the submit button.

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 mysql_select_db("maindb");
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {

    $title=isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : '';
    $description=isset($_POST['description']) ? $_POST['description'] : '';
    $district=isset($_POST['district']) ? $_POST['district'] : '';
    $phone=isset($_POST['phone']) ? $_POST['phone'] : '';
    $catagory=isset($_POST['catagory']) ? $_POST['catagory'] : '';
    $price=isset($_POST['price']) ? $_POST['price'] : '';
    if(!empty($title) && !empty($description) && !empty($district) && !empty($phone) && !empty($catagory) && !empty($price))
    {
        $q = mysql_query("INSERT into allads VALUES(NULL,'$title','$phone','$description', '$price','$district','$catagory')");
        if($q)
        {
            echo "<span style='background-color: deepskyblue;'>Your advert is now online!</span>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Could not update DB";
        }
    }

 }

 ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>emarket.com</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css"/>
    </head>
    <header>
        <h1><a href="index.php" style="text-decoration:none">emarket.com</a></h1>
        <h1><a href="postad.php" style="text-decoration:none; padding-left:700px">Post Ad</a></h1>
    </header>
    <body>

        <form class="postad" method="post" action="">
            <fieldset><caption><h2>Post New Advert</h2></caption></fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label>Title</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="title" class="form-text" required>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label>Description</label><br/>
                <input  name="description" class="form-text" required>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label>District</label><br/>
                <select name="district"required>
                    <option selected>Colombo</option>
                    <option>Kandy</option>
                    <option>Matara</option>
                    <option>Galle</option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label>Category</label><br/>
                <select name="catagory"required>
                    <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
                    <option value="Property">House and Property</option>
                    <option value="Auto">Automobiles</option>
                    <option value="Misc">Miscellaneous</option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label>Phone</label><br/>
                <input type="tel" name="phone" maxlength="10" class="form-text" required>
            </fieldset>         
            <fieldset>
                <label>Price</label><br/>
                Rs. <input type="number" name="price" class="form-text" required>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
?>
```

Edit :- IN situations like these, it's always better to put your php code before `<html>`
Also, what's your filename in which all this code exists? Put that filename in the `<Form action="filenamehere.php">`.
If it still doesn't work, upload it somewhere to let me have a closer look.

Comment: I tried again with your code, it did not work. Thank you so much for cleaning up, but I added required attribute to each input so none of them have null values. This is a school project so I don't have to worry about sql injection, they are not expecting me to either. Your code is really neat, I never knew you could test like that.

Comment: Honestly @Akshay, you should have also shown him how to escape. You could have done it in your ternaries - `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['etc'])`.

Comment: @Farkie
I wanted to. But then I didn't want to motivate him to keep going with mysql_*.

Comment: Some problem to you - Header should be inside body tag :)

Comment: @Farkie
Haha I agree, honestly, I didn't look at the HTML part. I only worked on PHP.

Comment: After making the changes 1. php before <html> , 2. <header> in <body>,  i still get the same result. Is there any reason why this works flawlessly in one browser and not in other. And also my form action is blank because the php code is in the same file

Comment: @p2sm 
Upload your file somewhere, so I can have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Your header tag should be inside the body tag.

```
<body>
    <header>
        <h1><a href="index.php" style="text-decoration:none">emarket.com</a></h1>
        <h1><a href="postad.php" style="text-decoration:none; padding-left:700px">Post Ad</a></h1>
    </header>
```

Like @Akshay said, you should be using PDO, however you should be escaping your input using something like mysql_real_escape_string($value) before putting it into the database if you aren't using PDO.